# jQuery removeClass problem

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a little bit of problem here:
I have the following js functions:

```
function setRounded(divId){
    $(divId).addClass("rounded-corners");
}
function unsetRounded(divId){
    $(divId).removeClass("rounded-corners");
}
```

This two functions are called before and after an event: for example I have the following page:[Testing page](http://badeasorin.com/show/) and i want to remove the rounded corners when i flip the block but it doesn't happen. Is there any refresh method ? I goggled a little bit but nothing similar.

Regards,
Sorin!

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to. You have it removing the rounded corners, then flipping the box then adding the rounded corners again. Please clarify what you are expecting.

Comment: Can you further explain how this is being called?

Comment: Might be browser issues: in firefox, I never see the corners going square. The class is only removed after the animation completes, then immediately added back.

Comment: Actually, in firefox, both the remove and the add are happening just the reapplication is happening once the image comes around. If you set break points on both the set/unset method you will see that they are actually both getting hit and the corners are being removed. You might see if there is an animation speed setting in the flip plugin to slow things down.

Comment: Only the left corner is going square.  The right top remains round which means possibly a class mis-match or a div mis-match?

Comment: @Liam Bailey - in Chrome the flipping effect with rounded corners doesn't look goog at all so i thought that if i remove the rounded corners before the flip effect it will look nice.

Comment: @griegs. Depends on what type of browser you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, in fact the class is removed from the div. However the flip plugin seems to create a copy of the div to create the flipping effect, and that copy of the div still has the class.

You could try to remove the class before calling .flip on it, instead of using onBefore.

Comment: you're welcome. I suggest you use Firebug or Chrome built in javascript debugger. I placed a brak point on the line with the removeClass, then executed it, and watched in the HTML/CSS tab why the div was still actually having borders, and there noticed the copy of the div.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves very inconsistently in Firefox 6.0. Have you tried changing:

```
$("#aboutMe").click(function(){
    $("#aboutMe").flip({
         onBefore:function(){
             unsetRounded("#aboutMe"); 
             return;
         },
         ...
    });
 });
```

to:

```
$("#aboutMe").click(function(){
    unsetRounded("#aboutMe");
    $("#aboutMe").flip({
        ...
    });
 });
```

Comment: i've solved the problem with $("#aboutMe").removeClass("rounded-corners").flip({[...]});

Comment: That *is* a better way - I guess I thought you were wedded to your 'unsetRounded' function :-)